# Why don't system("cls") or system("clear") work in vscode c++? (c++17 gcc)

Tags: c++, gcc

They don't clear the terminal after the program be finished.

I tried flushing the output stream but nothing.

It prints abnormal messages.

System() overall does that but if I remove it from the code, the output returns normal.

Comment: Because system() runs a new terminal instance and executes commands there not affecting the original terminal.

Comment: Why would you even call them? Depending on out of process system calls  is always going to be fragile and non-portable. For more control over your terminal see : [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)

Comment: The behaviour of those commands is terminal-dependent. The VS Code terminal only scrolls the output.

Comment: Side note: `system()` is a security *nightmare*, it should *never* be used (and IMHO should be deprecated and eventually removed from the standard library).